# Having trouble getting the .contains method to detect whether or not a ship is afloat

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to check my ArrayList for ships that have sunk using the .contains method. 2 out of the 5 ships are supposed to be sunk but my code keeps bringing back all 5 as sunk.

I thought I could do it with a simple

```
if(fleetList.contains(data.isAfloat()) == false)
```

Is there is a method or something that I am missing? I can't figure it out even after several google searches and re-reading of text.

```
public class ShipTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ARRAY OF SHIPS IN MAIN");
        Ship cs1 = new CruiseShip("Caribbean", 2700, true, 1998, "Magic");
        Ship cs2 = new CruiseShip("Atlantic Ocean", 1300, false, 1912, "Titanic");
        
        Ship cgs1 = new CargoShip("containers", 391, false, 1974, "El Faro");
        
        CargoShip cgs2 = new CargoShip("crude oil", 564763, false, 1979, "Seawise Giant");
        
        Ship ws1 = new WarShip("super carrier", "United States Navy", true, 1972, "USS Nimitz");
        
        Ship[] fleet = {cs1, cs2, cgs1, cgs2, ws1};
        for (int i = 0; i < fleet.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(fleet[i]);
        }
        
        List<Ship> fleetList = new ArrayList<Ship>();
        Collections.addAll(fleetList, fleet);
        
        shipShow(fleetList);
    }
    
    public static void shipShow(List<Ship> fleetList ) {
        System.out.println("ARRAY LIST OF SHIPS FROM METHOD");
        fleetList.remove(2);
        Ship ws2 = new WarShip("attack submarine", "United States Navy", true, 2015, "USS John Warner");
        fleetList.add(ws2);
        int sunk = 0;
        for (Ship data : fleetList) {
            System.out.println(data);
            if(fleetList.contains(data.isAfloat()) == true)
            {
                sunk += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sunk + " of these ships sank!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `contains` will check if a `List` contains exactly the provided object. Though you're checking if your `List` does contain the result of `isAfloat()` which (I guess) makes no sense. When you replace your `if(fleetList.contains(data.isAfloat()) == true)` statement with `if(data.isAfloat())` your code should work as expected.

Comment: Gave it a try and go figure that worked, I guess I was just over-complicating it after all! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of paintings you like, and I ask you: Hey, uh, are eggs on the list, you will probably answer "what the heck? This is a list of paintings, it's not a grocery list."

But there is a technical answer too: No, 'eggs' are (obviously) not on this list of paintings.

And that's exactly how java works. No, `data.isAfloat()`, which is a boolean (`true` or `false`) is obviously not in the list of ships, no.

You're already looping through ships (`for (Ship data : fleetList)`). There is no need to further refer to `fleetList` *inside* of that loop.

All you want is `if (data.isAfloat())`. (`== true` is not needed either. `data.isAfloat()` already returns a boolean value, it already returns true or false).

Answer (score 0):

```
int sunk = 0;
for (Ship data : fleetList) {
    System.out.println(data);
    if(fleetList.contains(data.isAfloat()) == true)
    {
        sunk += 1;
    }
}
System.out.println(sunk + " of these ships sank!");
```

can be replaced with below snippet

```
  Predicate<Ship> aFloatShipFilter = (Ship s) -> s.isAfloat();
    
    List<Ship> afloatShipList = fleetList.stream().filter(aFloatShipFilter).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    System.out.println(afloatShipList.size() + " of these ships sank!");
```

Comment: Let's start to confuse a beginner even more, recommending more advanced concepts like `Stream`s.

Answer (score 0):

fleetList.remove(2) removes the single element with index 2 from the list. This is the container ship since Java Lists uses zero based indexing. It does not remove two elements from the list.

Instead of removing sunk ships from your fleetList, you can set a flag inside the Ship class instance to indicate sinking. My version of your shipShow method is one way to do this.

```
public static void shipShow (List<Ship> fleetList)
{
    System.out.println ("ARRAY LIST OF SHIPS FROM METHOD");
    // Remove this: fleetList.remove (2);
    fleetList.get (2).setFloating (false);
    final Ship ws2 = new WarShip ("attack submarine", "United States Navy", true, 2015, "USS John Warner");
    fleetList.add (ws2);
    int sunk = 0;
    for (final Ship data : fleetList)
    {
        System.out.println (data);
        if (!data.isAfloat ())
        {
            sunk += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println (sunk + " of these ships sank!");
}
```

The Ship class would look something like this:

```
class Ship
{
    private boolean floating = true;

    public Ship (String typeName, int tonnage, boolean b, int date, String shipName)
    {
    }

    public void setFloating (boolean flag)
    {
        floating = flag;
    }

    public boolean isAfloat ()
    {
        return floating;
    }
}
```

You also need subclasses for WarShip, CruiseShip and CargoShip.